# Aurelia-testing: Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'

Tags: aurelia

I am using for the first time the `aurelia-testing` package to test my HTML code.

I seem to have followed [the docs](https://aurelia.io/docs/testing/components#testing-a-custom-element) to set up my test as follows:

```
describe('Contextual Menu HTML View test suite', function () {
  let component: ComponentTester;

  beforeEach(function () {
    component = StageComponent
      .withResources('../../src/components/modal/contextual-menu')
      .inView('<contextual-menu is-active.two-way="activateMenu"></contextual-menu>')
      .boundTo({ activateMenu: false });
  });

  it('should not add the is-active class to the root element', async function () {
    await component.create(bootstrap);
    const rootElement = await waitForDocumentElement('.qa-contextual-menu');
    expect(rootElement.classList.contains('is-active')).toBe(false);
  });

  afterEach(function () {
    component.dispose();
  });
});
```

I tried using just `bind` instead of `two-way` but that fails too.
I tried both with a `document.querySelector` and with `waitForDocumentElement`, both cases fail, but anyways I assume the error comes from earlier.

I am getting an error and I am not sure why. Could you put on the tracks to identify the root cause of the following:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'replaceChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
  at Object.convert (/Users/lemoustachiste/work/lm-frontend/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/Node.js:573:11)
at HTMLDivElement.replaceChild (/Users/lemoustachiste/work/lm-frontend/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/Node.js:292:31)
at NodeJsDom.replaceNode (/Users/lemoustachiste/work/lm-frontend/node_modules/aurelia-pal-nodejs/dist/nodejs-dom.js:95:29)
at makeElementIntoAnchor (/Users/lemoustachiste/work/lm-frontend/node_modules/aurelia-templating/dist/commonjs/aurelia-templating.js:2432:19)
at applyInstructions (/Users/lemoustachiste/work/lm-frontend/node_modules/aurelia-templating/dist/commonjs/aurelia-templating.js:2479:17)
at ViewFactory.create (/Users/lemoustachiste/work/lm-frontend/node_modules/aurelia-templating/dist/commonjs/aurelia-templating.js:2707:7)
at TemplatingEngine.enhance (/Users/lemoustachiste/work/lm-frontend/node_modules/aurelia-templating/dist/commonjs/aurelia-templating.js:5290:24)
at /Users/lemoustachiste/work/lm-frontend/node_modules/aurelia-framework/dist/commonjs/aurelia-framework.js:176:28
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at Aurelia.enhance (/Users/lemoustachiste/work/lm-frontend/node_modules/aurelia-framework/dist/commonjs/aurelia-framework.js:174:12)
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: I think your relative path to the resource might not be right. If you are using this with webpack (for bundling for karma), then you might want to to drop the `../../src` part, as normal src should be included in `resolve.modules` in webpack config.

Comment: If I drop the `../../src` part, then I get an error with "file not found". Do you know if there is a way to do a low level debug of what's being loaded?

Comment: Is it possible for you to share a minimal repo that reproduces this problem?

Comment: I'll try and set up something. Could it be related to jest and jsdom?

Comment: @SayanPal here is the repro: https://github.com/lemoustachiste/repro-aurelia-testing-component. I am in the same state as with my current project. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a jest user. So I simply used the scaffolded TS jest skeleton app from aurelia-cli (`au new jest-skeleton --unattended --select typescript,jest,vscode`). And found that to be working.

It seems the you are missing the following configuration in your `jest.config.js`.

```js
testEnvironment: "node",
```

After only adding that, the tests started working.